# React Native + react-native-ble-plx. Writing to a BLE device

Tags: reactjs, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, react-native-ble-plx

I'm writing an app with React Native and react-native-ble-plx. i already have scan devices, connect to a device and read from a device. everything works as expected.

My main issue is writing to the device.
the device I'm writing to doesn't have characteristics for each function. it has 3 services (device service, read service and write service). to differentiate between write to write there are prefixes.

**for example:**

**write password (4 digits)** - it will expect `0x5501` prefix and then password `01020304`.  so the payload will look like this: `0x550101020304`.

**write to lock the device (boolean 0/1)** - will be `0x5505` prefix, `01020304` password for security, `01` or `00` to lock / unlock the device. the payload will look like this: `0x550501020301` or `0x55050102030400`

---

When im trying to write to the device (set password). im not getting error, but also the device is not really changing the password. (testing with nordic actually changing the password to the device, so the device is working as expected).
what i tried (doesnt work):

```
    const prefix = [55, 1];
    let passwordWithHeader = [];
    if (data) {
      if (data.length < 4) throw new Error("Password must be 4 digits");

      passwordWithHeader = Buffer.from(
        convertedArrayToHex(prefix.concat(data)) // will return ["55","01","01","02","03","04"]
      );
    }

    try {
      let res =
        await connectedDevice.device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService(
          SPS_SERVICE_UUID,
          SPS_SERVER_TX_UUID,
          passwordWithHeader.toString("base64")
        );

      return res;
      // Password set successfully
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("err in write password", error);
      throw error;
      // Handle error while setting password
    }
  };
```

**Basically my question is, how to write data with ble plx lib, to a device that expects** `0x550101020304`?

probably my confusion is that based on the react-native-ble-plx it expects the data to be base16 [Writing to devce doc](https://github.com/dotintent/react-native-ble-plx/wiki/Characteristic-Writing) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im answering my own question.
So basically the main issue was that the device is expecting the prefix to be [55, 1] (as bytes) . this means that when im converting to hex (and then to base64) i need the 55 (index 0) to be a number that will be converted into 55 (which is 85).
so the final solution will look like this:

```
 const prefix = [85, 1];
    let passwordWithHeader = [];
    if (data) {
      if (data.length < 4) throw new Error("Password must be 4 digits");
    }
    passwordWithHeader = Buffer.from(prefix.concat(data));
   
    // Convert to hex (will now return [55,1,1,2,3,4])
    const hexString = passwordWithHeader.toString("hex");
    
    // Convert hex to base64
    const base64String = Buffer.from(hexString, "hex").toString("base64");

    try {
      let res =
        await connectedDevice?.device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService(
          SPS_SERVICE_UUID,
          SPS_SERVER_TX_UUID,
          base64String
        );

      return res;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("err in write password", error);
      throw error;
    }
```